# where do I find reference for linalg.get_lapack_funcs('geqrf')

Tags: scipy, lapack

I looked up on scipy manual,

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/genindex.html#G

but don't see this 'gearf' function anywhere.

Does any one recognize it and can provide documentation for it?

Comment: Where did you find a mention of this?

Comment: See the [naning convention of Lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node24.html): `geqrf`  refers to QR factorization (qrf) of general matrices (ge). But a type is need for the elements of the matrix: s, d, c or z.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is not just `geqrf` but [`dgeqrf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgeqrf.html) or [`sgeqrf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.sgeqrf.html) or [`cgeqrf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.cgeqrf.html) or [`zgeqrf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.zgeqrf.html)?

Look at the Scipy examples [here](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.linalg.get_lapack_funcs.html) to see how they use `get_lapack_funcs()` without specifying the type.

Comment: see https://github.com/gelman/ep-stan/blob/master/dep/method.py line 26

Comment: If you read the documentation for [`get_lapack_funcs()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.get_lapack_funcs.html) carefully, you'll find that it says there: "Arrays can be given to determine optimal prefix of LAPACK routines. If not given, double-precision routines will be used, otherwise the most generic type in arrays will be used."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access directly to the LAPACK routine then it is accesible via

```
scipy.linalg.lapack.sgeqtrf
scipy.linalg.lapack.dgeqtrf
scipy.linalg.lapack.cgeqtrf
scipy.linalg.lapack.zgeqtrf
```

or you can use what Antimony suggested.

But this is already wrapped via [`scipy.linalg.qr`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/linalg/decomp_qr.py#L134). If you set `pivoting` to `True`, `?geqr3` is used and otherwise `?geqrf` is used in the background.